# Django - rendering two dimensional dictionary data to template

Tags: python, django, dictionary, chart.js

For my polling project using [chartjs](http://www.chartjs.org/). In chart there would be multiple lines same as poll options. For example -

Are you a programmer?

1. Yes
2. No

Then chart would generate 2 lines for `Yes` and `No` vote records.

In `view`, I created a two dimensional `dictionary` to store poll options.

But I am facing problem with rendering two dimensional `dictionary` data to template. In template file I coded for `chartjs`. There is an option to set data for lines like following code -

```
datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
```

Above code generates single line but I need to make it dynamic for multiple lines.

Here is my two dimensional `dictionary` dataset -

```
{8: {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0, 12: 0}, 7: {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 1, 12: 0}}
```

I am trying to create dataset with following code -

```
{% for key, value in vote_records.items %}
            {% list = [] %}
            {% for single_key, single_value in value.items %}
            {% list.append(single_value) %}
            {% endfor %}
            {
                    label: '# for Vote',
                    data: {{ list }},
                    backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
            },
            {% endfor %}
```

But this is not the right way in template. How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do list manipulation in a template. It's not quite clear what you want to do, but looks like you just need to pass the values of each inner dict to your JS function.

```
{% for key, value in vote_records.items %}
        {
                label: '# for Vote',
                data: {{ value.values }},
                backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                ],
                borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
        },
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: yes, this is my main issue. Does it - `{{ value.values }}` generate a list? I am pretty new to Django.

Comment: That's not a Django question, but standard Python. Try it in the shell: `x = {1:0, 2:0, 3:1}; x.values()`

Comment: That shows dict_values([0, 0, 1]). Can I work with that to get list [0, 0, 1] or need some customization?

Comment: Ah, I'd forgotten it does that in Python 3. You would have to use the `join` filter then, and wrap it in brackets manually: `data: [ {{ value.values|join:", " }} ],`

Comment: Alternatively, you might consider dumping the whole dictionary to JSON in your view, and iterating over it directly in Javascript rather than in the template language.

Comment: does it generate list? I see it is showing string `0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0` not a list

Comment: I fixed the issue with JSON dumps. Thanks @Daniel